# VSIX - include other application in package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

How can we include a separate .NET application inside a VSIX package?  Preferably in a subdirectory so that it doesn't interfere with DLLs of the Visual Studio extension itself (different versions). The application is available in the same solution, but for the same reason I van also not add a reference to it in the main project.

The intention is to run that application as a separate process, started by the extension. The extension will then connect to that application through WCF.

Comment: Create your own installer and do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain you just need to include the .EXE in your .VSIX. A .VSIX is just a .zip file, and you can include additional files into it by simply adding them to your project and setting the Include in VSIX property to true.

To confirm, try downloading something like the [Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools VSIX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ADLTools.AzureDataLakeandStreamAnalyticsTools) to disk. (I mention this one because I noticed it installed a number of .EXE's under my C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions directory).

Once you have the .VSIX on disk, rename it as a .zip file and unzip, or view its contents with the windows explorer. Note that the extensions.vsixmanifest file contained in that .zip has no references or entries for any of the .exe files installed by that .VSIX. Which means, all you really need to do is include it in the .zip file.

Add a subfolder to your .VSIX project, copy the .exe there, add it to your project, set the Include In VISX property to true, and I suspect you'll be all set.

Sincerely,

Comment: It's much more than just the exe. The number of files is also more or less dynamic. 
Will this approach also include debug or release files, depending on the selected configuration?

Comment: No, it simply includes the specific files you add. If you need something more dynamic, add the other projects to your solution, and then use a Project to Project reference to include the output of the referenced project in the .VSIX. But that may result in a lot of extra/unneeded assemblies being included into the .VSIX.